Run ANY app in the background
The first part is the same as my previous question, but this question is different, bear with me.
Setup working right now, but with minor inconveniences:

app: Com Intercom - https://apkpure.com/com-intercom/com.dcco.app.Com/download
app connects using wifi, no accounts, no server/client separate apps
one phone/app configured as Door - shows large button
one/multiple phones/apps configured as Room - shows clock, speaker, view, hang-up buttons.
press button on Door phone, all Room phones ring, answer - show Door camera, option to speak/hang-up, automatically record short video

Inconveniences:

Room app has to be running all the time in foreground
Room phone has to have screen on, unlocked

Question:

Is there a way to run ANY app in the background, "minimised" (I'm mainly a Windows guy), with screen off / locked?

I have found some "fake turn off" apps that just put a black overlay over the screen, but that's of no help.
I'm not talking about coding my own app from scratch.
I mean use an existing app to run ANY other app in the background, "minimised" (think of pressing Home button to go to Home screen, all apps are minimised / sent to background), and with screen off.



All I was able to find is "create app from scratch, using standard Android Background work / Services overview or some alternative function" .
Edit: old app (2015), old phone (J4+, HTC Desire 530, Allview X4 Sould Infinity L), old Android (6, 7, 8, 10, 12)

Recent apps have background services for such actions. However "Com Intercom" is a bit outdated, it targets Android 4.4 (API 19) and does not define any services and has nor arm-v8 (64bit) support). Such old apps are already blocked for Android 14+, which means you can not install them anymore.

Forgot to mentio: old app, old phone, old Android.
I will edit question.

A few points: 1) Android got progressively strict about background work starting from Android 6 (Doze mode) 2) See if app pinning works for you, otherwise you'll need to look into "kiosk mode" if you want one app to be exclusively running.

Background work and screen pinning: I can use almost any old Android version, that's not a problem. Screen pinning: looks like it works with newer version, so it doesn't help. Also, That's not really the problem, I can just leave the app running and screen on. But that would drain the battery, burn the screen - also NOT real problems. But I would like to also use personal phone, around the house, to receive rings. Not just a dedicated phone, either in a  fixed spot or carry around 2 phones around the house.
